# ReferenceInput field shows progress bar but never resolves

Tags: react-admin

Throwing out the answer for anyone else who has this issue.

I have 1 resource that I couldn't using in a ReferenceInput. Progress Bar just spun. I could see in the dev tools that the response came back with data.

Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I missed the "Content Range" header in the API. In React-Admin, every GetMany request has to have a Content Range header in the response. You get an error if that API request is on a list, but in a ReferenceInput tag, you just get an infinity progress spinner.